# CSRF token mismatch in scribe/laravel

Tags: laravel, scribe, csrf-token, laravel-sanctum

I'm developing an REST API in laravel with middleware sanctum for authentication. I'm using Postman for testing and it's all ok, specially on login.
[image: Good login with postman]

But meanwhile, I'm already trying to developing documentation for my API (it's my final project at University) and I'm using scribe (https://scribe.knuckles.wtf/laravel) for that.
Scribe has a functionality that permits "Try it out" the API endpoints.
[image: scribe "Try it out"]

All "GET" endpoints are ok, but "POST" login endpoint is giving an error "CSRF token mismatch":

```
{
"message": "CSRF token mismatch.",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
"file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
"line": 227,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
        "line": 199,
        "function": "prepareException",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
        "line": 59,
        "function": "render",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 51,
        "function": "render",
        "class": "App\\Exceptions\\Handler",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 172,
        "function": "handleException",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php",
        "line": 116,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php",
        "line": 62,
        "function": "handleStatefulRequest",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
        "line": 37,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php",
        "line": 67,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\sanctum\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php",
        "line": 26,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 149,
        "function": "Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}",
        "class": "Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 103,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\sanctum\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php",
        "line": 34,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 103,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
        "line": 687,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
        "line": 662,
        "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
        "line": 628,
        "function": "runRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
        "line": 617,
        "function": "dispatchToRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
        "line": 165,
        "function": "dispatch",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 128,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
        "line": 27,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
        "line": 63,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php",
        "line": 52,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
        "line": 57,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
        "line": 103,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
        "line": 140,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
        "line": 109,
        "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\dbgep-api\\public\\index.php",
        "line": 55,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    }
]
```

}

I tried already changing some scribe options, but with no success.

I notice that on Postman testing I have on xsrf cookie, that probably it is the key for no error on postman (I confess that this project is a challenge and I am learning many things and don't know other things), but I don't know how to configure "scribe" to replicating this.
[image: XSRF cooki on postman]

I anyone could help me I would be grateful.... sorry about my english

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with Laravel Sanctum and Scribe, and finally found the solution in the [documentation](https://scribe.knuckles.wtf/laravel/reference/config#try_it_out).

If you're using Sanctum with scribe, you have to set :

config/scribe.php

```
'use_csrf' => true, //default false
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I created another "window" on Postman, and I didn't have to define any cookie "xsrf", and login works very well:

[image]

So, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? Using VerifyCsrfToken protected $except = [] adding my route didn't work for me. Also tried VsCode Thunder extension, same result.